# convert a table in SAS

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlh8D.jpg

i have the above data set, i want to convert the data set into a new data set with only 3 column, so as to do the logistic regression.

I want the 1st column to be the no. in each of the cell(i.e. i will have 14*6 data)

the 2nd column is the current level(i.e 0 1 2 3 4 5)

the 3rd column is the block no.(1 or 2) which will further convert to indicator variable

this is a past exam question, the solution used a modified data set which is already a 84*3 matrix.So i want to know how to convert the above data into a 84*3 data

Comment: Your question asks for four columns but you only describe three of them.

Comment: sorry for that, it should be 3 instead

Comment: try [`proc transpose`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000063662.htm)

Comment: i have tried proc transpose and dont have any idea on it, any suggestion?@miraculixx

Comment: Post your proc transpose code it should be very straightforward code.

Comment: Can you post the data?  Your picture does not look like a dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (not surprisingly) would use `proc sql`:

```
proc sql;
    create table newt as
        select blockno, 0 as lev, level_0 as val from t union all
        select blockno, 1 as lev, level_1 as val from t union all
        select blockno, 2 as lev, level_2 as val from t union all
        select blockno, 3 as lev, level_3 as val from t union all
        select blockno, 4 as lev, level_4 as val from t union all
        select blockno, 5 as lev, level_5 as val from t ;
```

Your picture doesn't make clear what the actual variable names are so I just guessed.

Comment: why it will occur error when i not using union all,i.e. only use "select blockno, 0 as lev, level_0 as val from t" in every row

Comment: @CCKKLLGG Perhaps looking through some documentation may answer that for you... http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/69049/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0vo2lglyrnexwn14emi8m0jqvrj.htm